# Proof of Hurwitz theorem.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Consider two integer $p, q$ and some irrational number $\alpha$.

As we know, $$\left|\alpha - \frac{p}{q}\right| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}q^2}.$$

I want to know how I can get it using Minkowski's theorem.

Comment: What preliminary work have you made? For example, have you searched for relevant articles? I'm just saying, because your question otherwise sounds like "can you please feed me with a spoon?".

Comment: @barakmanos it better to say: "can you give an idea to show the connection between Minkowski's theorem and Hurwitz's one"